# How to copy array behaviour?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I know that an array in JavaScript is nothing else than an object.
When I define an array like that:

```
var array;
array = [ "a", "b", "c" ];
```

and run

```
Object.keys(array);
```

I get following array: `["0", "1", "2"]`. Array length of `array` is `3`.

When I add a property like:

```
array["a"] = "d";
```

`Object.keys()` is returning `["0", "1", "2", "a"]`, but array length of `array` is still `3`.

But when I add a property like that:

```
array["3"] = "d";
```

the length of `array` is now `4`.

**If `array` is just another object, how can I achieve that kind of behaviour when I start my object from scratch like `var myArray = {}`?**

Comment: [Read this classic blog post from Kangax](http://perfectionkills.com/how-ecmascript-5-still-does-not-allow-to-subclass-an-array/) - it turns out that you cannot do what you're asking.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript array length incorrect on array of objects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2528680/javascript-array-length-incorrect-on-array-of-objects)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.length` property only includes properties with numeric indices, specifically those with integer values greater than or equal to zero.

If you're asking how to get a total count of *all* keys from an array or an object then you could do:

```
Object.keys(array).length
```

...since `Object.keys()` returns an array that will itself have a `.length` property.

Comment: P.S. Note that `.length` could actually be _greater_ than `Object.keys(array).length` because (as pointed out by Clyde) the length is one greater than the highest integer index, but JS allows sparse arrays and `Object.keys()` only returns indexes that have actually been assigned.

Comment: So I am guessing that the value of `length` is calculated every time a new property is added to the object?

Answer (score 1):

The `length` property of array is the value of the highest numerical index + 1.

So after `array["3"] = "d";` the highest numeric index is `3` hence the length returns `4`

`Object.keys(array).length` should give you the length.

Comment: `array[1000000000] = "x"` does not operate that way. Where is the limit?

Comment: Try `var array;
array = [ "a", "b", "c" ];
array[1000000000] = 1;
array.length;`

Comment: Add another `0` to the index and try again please.

Comment: @Amberlamps : This is the reason why : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6154989/maximum-size-of-an-array-in-javascript#