# Jquery: filter function

Tags: jquery

I go through a list of classes using the filter function. if the drop down is empty then an error styling is added.

**problem.**
I would like to hide and show other div id's if the condition is fulfilled, i.e if all the dropdowns contain a selected value

This is my code for adding styling to an empty dropdown

```
 $(".dropdown_select").filter(function(){
 return $(this).val() == "";
 }).css("border-color", "#FF0000");
```

But how do i go about hiding and showing a other two div id's?? i.e only if all dropdowns are filled, i would like to

```
$(".step-2").fadeIn("slow");
$(".step-1").fadeOut("slow");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For styling I'd recommend using `toggleClass()` with a function argument instead of `filter()` and `css()`:

```
$(document).on("change", ".dropdown_select", function () {
  var $emptyOnes = $(".dropdown_select")
                   .filter(function () { return this.value == ""; });

  if ($emptyOnes.length == 0) {
    $(".step-1").fadeOut("slow");
    $(".step-2").fadeIn("slow");
  } 

  $(this).toggleClass("empty", this.value == "");
});
```

where tre CSS definition reads:

```
.empty {
  border-color: #FF0000;
}
```

Comment: $emptyOnes.length is always evaluating to 0.....im not sure but as i read i think its because its not real array, from this post http://stackoverflow.com/a/2528893/1214535 ...have a look at this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/theunfeelingsoul/CJAhz/3/

Comment: No. `$emptyOnes.length` is only 0 when all `.dropdown_select` elements have a value. Which is what you wanted (quote *"i.e only if all dropdowns are filled, i would like to…"*).

Comment: yea that's what i want but that's not happening, whether the dropdown has a value or not it still evaluates to 0...i dont know why. have a look at the jsfiddle link and see...

Answer (score 1):

```
var $children = $(".dropdown_select").children();

if($children.length === $children.filter(".dropdown_select").length) {
   $(".step-2").fadeIn("slow");
   $(".step-1").fadeOut("slow");
}
```

Comment: I dont understand what $children.filter().length does because is resulting to 0 all the time....??