# Array.length is 0 even when it contains values - Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a parent array containing child-arrays. `length` property on parent array displays 0 results, even when there are child arrays present.

Here's the code:

```js
var balances = [];
balances['kanav'] = 50;
balances['yash'] = 50;

alert(balances.length);
console.log(balances);
```

What's the reason?

Comment: Please add the relevant [mcve] code to your question; don't just link to an e thermal resource.

Comment: The `length` property is defined as the highest index plus 1, or 0 if it doesn’t contain any indices. Those properties do not count as indices.

Comment: @Xufox—not exactly, *length* is **at least** the highest index plus one. It can be higher (e.g. `var a = new Array(8)`.

Comment: Why so many down-votes? Explaining problem with a JSFiddle example. Did i do anything wrong?

Comment: It looks like an array, but it's an object! Good explanation here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2528680/javascript-array-length-incorrect-on-array-of-objects

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [*length*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-properties-of-array-instances-length) property only works for Array properties that are numeric values. Arrays are just Objects with a special *length* property and some handy methods inherited from *Array.prototype*.

When you add properties like *kanav* and *yash*, they are added as plain object properties, not indexes, therefore don't affect *length*.

```js
var arr = [];

// Add plain object properties
arr.foo = 'foo';
arr.bar = 'bar';

document.write(arr.length) // 0

// Add some numeric properties
// Since they are numbers, square bracket notation must be used
arr[9] = 9;

document.write('<br>' + arr.length) // 10
```

Comment: Agree to @RobG. [JSFiddle for reference](http://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/1cvyjha6/7/)

Answer (score 1):

In your example balances is not an array, it is actually an associative array (they're both objects, but they have different methods).

If you want to use an array you could

```
var balances = [
    ["kanav", 50],
    ["yash", 50]
];
alert(balances.length);
console.log(balances);
```

If you wanted to stay with your current format you would have to loop over the objects to count them

```
var balances = [];
balances['kanav'] = 50;
balances['yash'] = 50;

var i=0;
for(var key in balances) {
    if(balances.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        i++;
    }
}
console.log(i);
```

Comment: `balances` is an array, and it is also an object. This still doesn’t answer the question.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the array as a json object, but an array handle indexes or push functions. Therefor if you use it in this way, it will produce the right result.

```
var balances = [];
balances.push('something');
balances.push('another');

alert(balances.length);
console.log(balances);
```

Or otherwise in this syntax:

```
var balances = [];
balances[0] = 50;
balances[1] = 50;

alert(balances.length);
console.log(balances);
```

Answer (score 0):

`balances` is an *associative array*.
According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5223/length-of-a-javascript-object-that-is-associative-array) post, you can obtain its length, in this way:

```
Object.size = function(obj) {
    var size = 0, key;
    for (key in obj) {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key))
            size++;
    }
    return size;
};

var balances = [];
balances['kanav'] = 50;
balances['yash'] = 50;

alert(Object.size(balances));
console.log(balances);
```