# JavaScript Array.length returning 0

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have javascript Array that looks like [image]

The problem is `Object.mappings` has 3 elements which are clearly printed in console with `console.log()`, but when I try to find length of the array it returns `0`. I tried stringifying the array and it just prints "[]".

what Am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Can you post the actual code?  That would be more helpful.

Comment: This is an array with properties, array item use integer keys so the array does not contain any item

Comment: Have a look at this similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2528680/javascript-array-length-incorrect-on-array-of-objects

Comment: how do you add elements into array ? probably you can get your "lenght" in other way, using `Object.keys(object.mapping).forEach(do something)`

Comment: Looks more like an object to me.

Answer (score 5):

You can use length property only if array contains elements associated with indexes. If it is associative array then length property will return 0. You can count elements by yourself using this code:

```
function len(arr) {
  var count = 0;
  for (var k in arr) {
    if (arr.hasOwnProperty(k)) {
      count++;
    }
  }
  return count;
}
```

Then you can count elements of "mappings" array using `len(mappings)`

Answer (score 3):

JavaScript arrays does not work like those in for instance PHP which can work as associative arrays. However, due to JavaScript's dynamic nature, and the fact that an Array is a subclass of Object, you can still attach arbitrary properties on to a Array. The `length` property will however not reflect this (as you have discovered).

If you're using newer browsers/polyfills (like `core-js`), I recommend going with `Map` instead ([Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)). Otherwise, use a simple object (`{}`), and use `Object.keys` on the object to get the keys.

Example of the later:

```
var mappings = {};
mappings['foo'] = 'bar';
Object.keys(mappings); // returns ['foo']
mappings[Object.keys(mappings)[0]]; // returns 'bar'

// Loop through all key-value pairs
Object.keys(mappings).forEach(function(key) {
  var value = mappings[key];
  // Do stuff with key and value.
});
```

Answer (score 3):

From this [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length) article, the `length` property of an array represent an integer that's greater than the **highest index** in the array.

> The length property represents an unsigned, 32-bit integer that is always numerically greater than the highest index in the array.

When you assigned non integer keys to array, the highest index is still `0`.

```
var arr = [];
arr['abc'] = 1;
console.log(arr.length); //0
arr[100] = 2;
console.log(arr.length); //101
```