# Array length returning 0

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm having this weird issue where I have an array returned from a function:

```
let result = new Array();
result.push(compressedFile)
return result
```

Then I simply try to console.log the array's length and it's first value:

```
files = ****result from other function****
console.log(files)
console.log(files.length)
console.log(files[0])
console.log(files['0'])
```

And here's what's returned in the console:

[image: console screenshot]

The console clearly shows that the files variable holds values. What am I missing?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JavaScript Array.length returning 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36307213/javascript-array-length-returning-0)

Comment: It's not actually an array. It is an object. Where does `files` come from?

Comment: `files = ****result from other function****` - I bet there's asynchrony involved in this "other function"

Comment: Okay, so apparently I'm logging the array while it's empty and the inspecter is showing the live state of the array, i.e. after it was filled. @JaromandaX