# Parsing a HTML Table

Tags: vb.net, html-parsing, html-agility-pack, nullreferenceexception

So far I have the following code:

```
Dim wreqBalQtr As HttpWebRequest = WebRequest.Create("http://www.reuters.com/finance/stocks/incomeStatement/detail?stmtType=BAL&perType=INT&symbol=" & tickerValue)
wreqBalQtr.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US; rv:1.9.1.5) Gecko/20091102 Firefox/3.5.5"
wreqBalQtr.Method = "get"
Dim proxBalQtr As IWebProxy = wreqBalQtr.Proxy
proxBalQtr.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials
Dim documentBalQtr As New HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument
Dim webBalQtr As New HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb
webBalQtr.UseCookies = True
webBalQtr.PreRequest = New HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb.PreRequestHandler(AddressOf onPreReq)
wreqBalQtr.CookieContainer = cookies
Dim resBalQtr As HttpWebResponse = wreqBalQtr.GetResponse()
documentBalQtr.Load(resBalQtr.GetResponseStream, True)
Dim TotalCurrentAssets = documentBalQtr.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//table[@class='dataTable Financials']//tr[13]//td[3]")
```

And the HTML is:

```
<table class="dataTable financials" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0" width="100%">
  <tr>
    <th class="rh">
        <span class="units">
        In Millions of U.S. Dollars<br/>
        (except for per share items)<br/>
        </span>
    </th>
    <th class="data">
        2012<br/>
        2012-09-30<br/>
        <span class="period">
        </span>
      </th>
      <th class="data">
        2012<br/>
        2012-06-30<br/>
        <span class="period">
        </span>
      </th>
      <th class="data">
        2012<br/>
        2012-03-31<br/>
        <span class="period">
        </span>
      </th>
      <th class="data">
        2011<br/>
        2011-12-31<br/>
        <span class="period">
        Reclassified<br/>
        2012-06-30<br/>
        </span>
      </th>
      <th class="data">
        2011<br/>
        2011-09-30<br/>
        <span class="period">
        </span>
      </th>
      </tr>

  <tr class="both stripe ">
        <td class="rh">Cash</td>
        <td class="data plus">6,224.0</td>
          <td class="data plus">7,463.0</td>
          <td class="data plus">11,239.0</td>
          <td class="data plus">4,712.0</td>
          <td class="data plus">4,209.0</td>
          </tr>
      <tr class="both  ">
        <td class="rh">Cash & Equivalents</td>
        <td class="data plus">10,036.0</td>
          <td class="data plus">7,974.0</td>
          <td class="data plus">11,869.0</td>
          <td class="data plus">5,271.0</td>
          <td class="data plus">6,421.0</td>
          </tr>
      <tr class="both stripe ">
        <td class="rh">Short Term Investments</td>
        <td class="data plus">29,464.0</td>
          <td class="data plus">27,685.0</td>
          <td class="data plus">26,208.0</td>
          <td class="data plus">34,643.0</td>
          <td class="data plus">31,930.0</td>
          </tr>
      <tr class="both  ">
        <td class="rh">Cash and Short Term Investments</td>
        <td class="data plus">45,724.0</td>
          <td class="data plus">43,122.0</td>
          <td class="data plus">49,316.0</td>
          <td class="data plus">44,626.0</td>
          <td class="data plus">42,560.0</td>
          </tr>
      <tr class="both stripe ">
        <td class="rh">Accounts Receivable - Trade, Net</td>
        <td class="data plus">7,259.0</td>
          <td class="data plus">6,866.0</td>
          <td class="data plus">5,163.0</td>
          <td class="data plus">5,427.0</td>
          <td class="data plus">4,583.0</td>
          </tr>
      <tr class="both  ">
        <td class="rh">Notes Receivable - Short Term</td>
        <td class="data plus">--</td>
          <td class="data plus">--</td>
          <td class="data plus">--</td>
          <td class="data plus">--</td>
          <td class="data plus">--</td>
          </tr>
      <tr class="both stripe ">
        <td class="rh">Receivables - Other</td>
        <td class="data plus">550.0</td>
          <td class="data plus">475.0</td>
          <td class="data plus">550.0</td>
          <td class="data plus">745.0</td>
          <td class="data plus">1,278.0</td>
          </tr>
      <tr class="both  ">
        <td class="rh">Total Receivables, Net</td>
        <td class="data plus">7,809.0</td>
          <td class="data plus">7,341.0</td>
          <td class="data plus">5,713.0</td>
          <td class="data plus">6,172.0</td>
          <td class="data plus">5,861.0</td>
          </tr>
      <tr class="both stripe ">
        <td class="rh">Total Inventory</td>
        <td class="data plus">618.0</td>
          <td class="data plus">634.0</td>
          <td class="data plus">--</td>
          <td class="data plus">35.0</td>
          <td class="data plus">--</td>
          </tr>
      <tr class="both  ">
        <td class="rh">Prepaid Expenses</td>
        <td class="data plus">2,440.0</td>
          <td class="data plus">2,614.0</td>
          <td class="data plus">1,779.0</td>
          <td class="data plus">1,710.0</td>
          <td class="data plus">1,406.0</td>
          </tr>
      <tr class="sum stripe ">
        <td class="rh">Other Current Assets, Total</td>
        <td class="data plus">230.0</td>
          <td class="data plus">146.0</td>
          <td class="data plus">51.0</td>
          <td class="data plus">215.0</td>
          <td class="data plus">215.0</td>
          </tr>
      <tr class="both  total">
        <td class="rh">Total Current Assets</td>
        <td class="data plus">56,821.0</td>
          <td class="data plus">53,857.0</td>
          <td class="data plus">56,859.0</td>
          <td class="data plus">52,758.0</td>
          <td class="data plus">50,042.0</td>
          </tr>
      <tr class="both stripe ">
        <td class="rh">Property/Plant/Equipment, Total - Gross</td>
        <td class="data plus">17,038.0</td>
          <td class="data plus">16,137.0</td>
          <td class="data plus">14,963.0</td>
          <td class="data plus">14,400.0</td>
          <td class="data plus">13,815.0</td>
          </tr>
      <tr class="both  ">
        <td class="rh">Accumulated Depreciation, Total</td>
        <td class="data minus">(5,637.0)</td>
          <td class="data minus">(5,228.0)</td>
          <td class="data minus">(5,088.0)</td>
          <td class="data minus">(4,797.0)</td>
          <td class="data minus">(4,611.0)</td>
          </tr>
      <tr class="both stripe ">
        <td class="rh">Property/Plant/Equipment, Total - Net</td>
        <td class="data plus">11,401.0</td>
          <td class="data plus">10,909.0</td>
          <td class="data plus">9,875.0</td>
          <td class="data plus">9,603.0</td>
          <td class="data plus">9,204.0</td>
          </tr>
      <tr class="both  ">
        <td class="rh">Goodwill, Net</td>
        <td class="data plus">10,485.0</td>
          <td class="data plus">10,120.0</td>
          <td class="data plus">7,325.0</td>
          <td class="data plus">7,346.0</td>
          <td class="data plus">6,989.0</td>
          </tr>
      <tr class="both stripe ">
        <td class="rh">Intangibles, Net</td>
        <td class="data plus">7,754.0</td>
          <td class="data plus">7,862.0</td>
          <td class="data plus">1,541.0</td>
          <td class="data plus">1,578.0</td>
          <td class="data plus">1,474.0</td>
          </tr>
      <tr class="sum  ">
        <td class="rh">Long Term Investments</td>
        <td class="data plus">1,063.0</td>
          <td class="data plus">1,040.0</td>
          <td class="data plus">880.0</td>
          <td class="data plus">790.0</td>
          <td class="data plus">891.0</td>
          </tr>
      <tr class="both stripe ">
        <td class="rh">Note Receivable - Long Term</td>
        <td class="data plus">--</td>
          <td class="data plus">--</td>
          <td class="data plus">--</td>
          <td class="data plus">--</td>
          <td class="data plus">--</td>
          </tr>
      <tr class="sum  ">
        <td class="rh">Other Long Term Assets, Total</td>
        <td class="data plus">2,206.0</td>
          <td class="data plus">2,263.0</td>
          <td class="data plus">664.0</td>
          <td class="data plus">499.0</td>
          <td class="data plus">488.0</td>
          </tr>
      <tr class="sum stripe ">
        <td class="rh">Other Assets, Total</td>
        <td class="data plus">--</td>
          <td class="data plus">--</td>
          <td class="data plus">--</td>
          <td class="data plus">--</td>
          <td class="data plus">--</td>
          </tr>
      <tr class="both  total">
        <td class="rh">Total Assets</td>
        <td class="data plus">89,730.0</td>
          <td class="data plus">86,051.0</td>
          <td class="data plus">77,144.0</td>
          <td class="data plus">72,574.0</td>
          <td class="data plus">69,088.0</td>
          </tr>
      <tr class="both stripe ">
        <td class="rh">Accounts Payable</td>
        <td class="data plus">2,233.0</td>
          <td class="data plus">2,419.0</td>
          <td class="data plus">760.0</td>
          <td class="data plus">588.0</td>
          <td class="data plus">563.0</td>
          </tr>
      <tr class="both  ">
        <td class="rh">Payable/Accrued</td>
        <td class="data plus">--</td>
          <td class="data plus">--</td>
          <td class="data plus">--</td>
          <td class="data plus">--</td>
          <td class="data plus">--</td>
          </tr>
      <tr class="both stripe ">
        <td class="rh">Accrued Expenses</td>
        <td class="data plus">6,347.0</td>
          <td class="data plus">5,551.0</td>
          <td class="data plus">3,429.0</td>
          <td class="data plus">4,356.0</td>
          <td class="data plus">3,563.0</td>
          </tr>
      <tr class="both  ">
        <td class="rh">Notes Payable/Short Term Debt</td>
        <td class="data plus">3,218.0</td>
          <td class="data plus">3,218.0</td>
          <td class="data plus">2,468.0</td>
          <td class="data plus">1,218.0</td>
          <td class="data plus">1,218.0</td>
          </tr>
      <tr class="both stripe ">
        <td class="rh">Current Port. of  LT Debt/Capital Leases</td>
        <td class="data plus">--</td>
          <td class="data plus">--</td>
          <td class="data plus">--</td>
          <td class="data plus">--</td>
          <td class="data plus">--</td>
          </tr>
      <tr class="sum  ">
        <td class="rh">Other Current liabilities, Total</td>
        <td class="data plus">2,636.0</td>
          <td class="data plus">2,840.0</td>
          <td class="data plus">3,085.0</td>
          <td class="data plus">2,751.0</td>
          <td class="data plus">3,544.0</td>
          </tr>
      <tr class="both stripe total">
        <td class="rh">Total Current Liabilities</td>
        <td class="data plus">14,434.0</td>
          <td class="data plus">14,028.0</td>
          <td class="data plus">9,742.0</td>
          <td class="data plus">8,913.0</td>
          <td class="data plus">8,888.0</td>
          </tr>
      <tr class="both  ">
        <td class="rh">Long Term Debt</td>
        <td class="data plus">2,988.0</td>
          <td class="data plus">2,987.0</td>
          <td class="data plus">2,987.0</td>
          <td class="data plus">2,986.0</td>
          <td class="data plus">2,986.0</td>
          </tr>
      <tr class="both stripe ">
        <td class="rh">Capital Lease Obligations</td>
        <td class="data plus">--</td>
          <td class="data plus">--</td>
          <td class="data plus">--</td>
          <td class="data plus">--</td>
          <td class="data plus">--</td>
          </tr>
      <tr class="both  ">
        <td class="rh">Total Long Term Debt</td>
        <td class="data plus">2,988.0</td>
          <td class="data plus">2,987.0</td>
          <td class="data plus">2,987.0</td>
          <td class="data plus">2,986.0</td>
          <td class="data plus">2,986.0</td>
          </tr>
      <tr class="both stripe ">
        <td class="rh">Total Debt</td>
        <td class="data plus">6,206.0</td>
          <td class="data plus">6,205.0</td>
          <td class="data plus">5,455.0</td>
          <td class="data plus">4,204.0</td>
          <td class="data plus">4,204.0</td>
          </tr>
      <tr class="sum  ">
        <td class="rh">Deferred Income Tax</td>
        <td class="data plus">1,461.0</td>
          <td class="data plus">1,509.0</td>
          <td class="data plus">384.0</td>
          <td class="data plus">287.0</td>
          <td class="data plus">263.0</td>
          </tr>
      <tr class="both stripe ">
        <td class="rh">Minority Interest</td>
        <td class="data plus">--</td>
          <td class="data plus">--</td>
          <td class="data plus">--</td>
          <td class="data plus">--</td>
          <td class="data plus">--</td>
          </tr>
      <tr class="sum  ">
        <td class="rh">Other Liabilities, Total</td>
        <td class="data plus">2,819.0</td>
          <td class="data plus">2,806.0</td>
          <td class="data plus">2,319.0</td>
          <td class="data plus">2,243.0</td>
          <td class="data plus">2,121.0</td>
          </tr>
      <tr class="both stripe total">
        <td class="rh">Total Liabilities</td>
        <td class="data plus">21,702.0</td>
          <td class="data plus">21,330.0</td>
          <td class="data plus">15,432.0</td>
          <td class="data plus">14,429.0</td>
          <td class="data plus">14,258.0</td>
          </tr>
      <tr class="sum  ">
        <td class="rh">Redeemable Preferred Stock, Total</td>
        <td class="data plus">--</td>
          <td class="data plus">--</td>
          <td class="data plus">--</td>
          <td class="data plus">--</td>
          <td class="data plus">--</td>
          </tr>
      <tr class="sum stripe ">
        <td class="rh">Preferred Stock - Non Redeemable, Net</td>
        <td class="data plus">0.0</td>
          <td class="data plus">0.0</td>
          <td class="data plus">0.0</td>
          <td class="data plus">0.0</td>
          <td class="data plus">0.0</td>
          </tr>
      <tr class="sum  ">
        <td class="rh">Common Stock, Total</td>
        <td class="data plus">22,204.0</td>
          <td class="data plus">21,357.0</td>
          <td class="data plus">20,795.0</td>
          <td class="data plus">20,264.0</td>
          <td class="data plus">19,697.0</td>
          </tr>
      <tr class="both stripe ">
        <td class="rh">Additional Paid-In Capital</td>
        <td class="data plus">--</td>
          <td class="data plus">--</td>
          <td class="data plus">--</td>
          <td class="data plus">--</td>
          <td class="data plus">--</td>
          </tr>
      <tr class="both  ">
        <td class="rh">Retained Earnings (Accumulated Deficit)</td>
        <td class="data plus">45,456.0</td>
          <td class="data plus">43,280.0</td>
          <td class="data plus">40,495.0</td>
          <td class="data plus">37,605.0</td>
          <td class="data plus">34,901.0</td>
          </tr>
      <tr class="both stripe ">
        <td class="rh">Treasury Stock - Common</td>
        <td class="data plus">--</td>
          <td class="data plus">--</td>
          <td class="data plus">--</td>
          <td class="data plus">--</td>
          <td class="data plus">--</td>
          </tr>
      <tr class="both  ">
        <td class="rh">ESOP Debt Guarantee</td>
        <td class="data plus">--</td>
          <td class="data plus">--</td>
          <td class="data plus">--</td>
          <td class="data plus">--</td>
          <td class="data plus">--</td>
          </tr>
      <tr class="both stripe ">
        <td class="rh">Unrealized Gain (Loss)</td>
        <td class="data plus">566.0</td>
          <td class="data plus">389.0</td>
          <td class="data plus">416.0</td>
          <td class="data plus">327.0</td>
          <td class="data plus">99.0</td>
          </tr>
      <tr class="sum  ">
        <td class="rh">Other Equity, Total</td>
        <td class="data minus">(198.0)</td>
          <td class="data minus">(305.0)</td>
          <td class="data plus">6.0</td>
          <td class="data minus">(51.0)</td>
          <td class="data plus">133.0</td>
          </tr>
      <tr class="both stripe total">
        <td class="rh">Total Equity</td>
        <td class="data plus">68,028.0</td>
          <td class="data plus">64,721.0</td>
          <td class="data plus">61,712.0</td>
          <td class="data plus">58,145.0</td>
          <td class="data plus">54,830.0</td>
          </tr>
      <tr class="both  total">
        <td class="rh">Total Liabilities & Shareholders' Equity</td>
        <td class="data plus">89,730.0</td>
          <td class="data plus">86,051.0</td>
          <td class="data plus">77,144.0</td>
          <td class="data plus">72,574.0</td>
          <td class="data plus">69,088.0</td>
          </tr>
      <tr class="both stripe ">
        <td class="rh">Shares Outs - Common Stock Primary Issue</td>
        <td class="data plus">264.52</td>
          <td class="data plus">261.58</td>
          <td class="data plus">259.50</td>
          <td class="data plus">257.55</td>
          <td class="data plus">255.70</td>
          </tr>
      <tr class="both  ">
        <td class="rh">Shares Outstanding - Common Issue 2</td>
        <td class="data plus">64.04</td>
          <td class="data plus">65.36</td>
          <td class="data plus">66.40</td>
          <td class="data plus">67.34</td>
          <td class="data plus">68.05</td>
          </tr>
      <tr class="both stripe ">
        <td class="rh">Shares Outstanding - Common Issue 3</td>
        <td class="data plus">--</td>
          <td class="data plus">--</td>
          <td class="data plus">--</td>
          <td class="data plus">--</td>
          <td class="data plus">--</td>
          </tr>
      <tr class="both  ">
        <td class="rh">Shares Outstanding - Common Issue 4</td>
        <td class="data plus">--</td>
          <td class="data plus">--</td>
          <td class="data plus">--</td>
          <td class="data plus">--</td>
          <td class="data plus">--</td>
          </tr>
      <tr class="both stripe total">
        <td class="rh">Total Common Shares Outstanding</td>
        <td class="data plus">328.55</td>
          <td class="data plus">326.94</td>
          <td class="data plus">325.91</td>
          <td class="data plus">324.89</td>
          <td class="data plus">323.76</td>
          </tr>
      <tr class="both  total">
        <td class="rh">Total Preferred Shares Outstanding</td>
        <td class="data plus">--</td>
          <td class="data plus">--</td>
          <td class="data plus">--</td>
          <td class="data plus">--</td>
          <td class="data plus">--</td>
          </tr>
      </table>

</div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

When I try to use the variable TotalCurrentAssets to pull the second column from the Total Current Assets row (the number should be 53,857.0).  I get "NullReferenceException was unhandled by user code. Object reference not not set to an instance of object."

Does this mean that the variable TotalCurrentAssets returns nothing?  I'm assuming that my error is in my last line of code.

ADDITIONAL INFORMATION

I don't know if the impacts my problem or not but I run this code before the code from my original post:

```
Dim wreqBeta As HttpWebRequest = WebRequest.Create("http://www.reuters.com/finance/stocks/overview?symbol=" & tickerValue)
        wreqBeta.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US; rv:1.9.1.5) Gecko/20091102 Firefox/3.5.5"
        wreqBeta.Method = "get"
        Dim proxBeta As IWebProxy = wreqBeta.Proxy
        proxBeta.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials
        Dim documentBeta As New HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument
        Dim webBeta As New HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb
        webBeta.UseCookies = True
        webBeta.PreRequest = New HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb.PreRequestHandler(AddressOf onPreReq)
        wreqBeta.CookieContainer = cookies
        Dim resBeta As HttpWebResponse = wreqBeta.GetResponse()
        documentBeta.Load(resBeta.GetResponseStream, True)
        Dim beta = documentBeta.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@id='overallRatios']//table[@class='dataTable']//tr[1]//td[2]")
```

Do I need to close anything from this code before starting to parse the new webpage?

Comment: What's your `tickerValue` in the url? Then we could test it.

Comment: Sorry!  I am testing using tickerValue = GOOG.  Thanks!

Comment: XPath is actually 1 indexed... See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3319341/why-do-indexes-in-xpath-start-with-1-and-not-0

Comment: I just tried    Dim TotalCurrentAssets = documentBalQtr.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//table[@class='dataTable Financials']tr[12]td[2]") and it returned "'//table[@class='dataTable Financials']tr[12]td[2]' has an invalid token.

Comment: You can replace the `//` by `/`, not remove them altogether.

Comment: I see.  I tried Dim TotalCurrentAssets = documentBalQtr.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//table[@class='dataTable financials']/tr[13]/td[3]") but I am back to the same NullReferenceException error.

Comment: I tried your code and the HTML returned by the Uri you're calling does not contain a table with that class at all. Thus, it's logical that you're not finding the cell. Use `Console.WriteLine(documentBalQtr.DocumentNode.OuterHtml)` to see the HTML being returned. It looks like you're doing some form of authentication, but since you didn't include that code, I can't test that.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "doing some form of authentication".  What code should I include so that you would know?

Comment: What is the contents of the `onPreReq` method? Your code can use some better cleanup of IDisposable members, but that is probably not what's breaking it.

Comment: Private Function onPreReq(ByVal req As HttpWebRequest)

        req.CookieContainer = cookies
        Return True

    End Function

Comment: I believe that I have figured out my problem.  The webpage that I am trying to parse requires that I be logged in to access the page.  I believe that this is why the HTML does not contain the table I'm searching for.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Name matching for attributes is case sensitive. Your HTML contains `*f* inancials`, your code expects `*F* inancials`.

You can use `//table[upper-case(@class)=upper-case('dataTable financials')]` to prevent these type of issues when case sensitivity is not important. or you can use the XPath 2.0 `matches` function.

On top of that, make sure that the webpage you're accessing actually returns the data you're expecting. In my local test the page being returned does not contain a table with data similar to your sample.

Place a watch on `documentBalQtr.DocumentNode.OuterHtml` to verify your page actually matches what you're expecting.

Comment: I just changed it to     Dim TotalCurrentAssets = documentBalQtr.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//table[@class='dataTable financials']//tr[13]//td[3]")    but I got the same NullReferenceException error.

Comment: When you run it in the debugger, where exactly do you get the NullReferenceException, this works just fine on my machine, but I'm not fetching the file from the web, instead I just copy/pasted your HTML snippet to my visual studio solution. I expect you had more than one bug in your code to begin with.

Comment: I get the NullReferenceException at this line dr("Current Ratio (MRQ)") = TotalCurrentAssets.InnerText

Comment: Updated my answer to include the fact that the HTML being returned doesn't match what you're expecting. If this answers your question, please mark it as such.

Comment: I want to use Google Chrome open my webpages.  I need to change wreqBeta.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US; rv:1.9.1.5) Gecko/20091102 Firefox/3.5.5"  How do I do this?

Comment: Just replace `wreqBalQtr.UserAgent` with your string, instead of the FireFox link. But this will not actually use your browser to open the webpages. It will just trick the server into thinking you're connecting from Chrome. The .NET Framework will use its own internal routines to download the files. But that would be a different question.

Comment: I marked you answer.  Thank you very much!  In Chrome I have the username and password saved so that I don't have to always input them to access the webpage.  Will the server be tricked by this and allow me to access the page?  What string would I use for Chrome instead of FireFox?

Comment: No. The server will not be tricked. To log in, you will need to have your application submit the proper HTML post request and then store the cookies that the server returns. Can't you use a normal webservice to retrieve these values from somewhere? Again, post a different question for these types of answers.

Comment: What kind of normal webservice?  I have searched quite a bit for one that would work and have found nothing.  Anything that you could suggest would really help!

Comment: Yahoo offers a number of Finance related webservices. As are others. Some free, some paid. http://developer.yahoo.com/finance/company.html