# XPath select by index off by index

Tags: xml, xpath

I'm totally new to XPath and need to use it for a project.  My XML looks like

```
<AverageErrorRate>
    <float>0123</float>
    <float>0456</float>
</AverageErrorRate>
```

I'm using this site:
http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath

When I try to do:

```
/AverageErrorRate/float[0]
```

It just returns the same thing to me.  But if I do

```
/AverageErrorRate/float[1]
```

Then I get 0123 which is what I want.  Am I missing something about the way XPath works?

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3319341/why-do-indexes-in-xpath-start-with-1-and-not-0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/AverageErrorRate/float[0]
```

is not returning the same thing, it returns nothing.

> INFO - XPath returned 0 items

[Indexes in XPath start at 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3319341/why-do-indexes-in-xpath-start-with-1-and-not-0), therefore the website is correct.

Also note that you're not getting `0123`, you're getting `<float>0123</float>`, which is the whole element. If you want the text only, use

```
/AverageErrorRate/float[1]/text()
```