# selenium explicitly wait, wait until a list of buttons are clickable

Tags: javascript, angularjs, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

In a page there are a list of buttons. Source code of each button is the same except for the link text.

I need to confirm the all the buttons in one page are clickable using WebDriverWait.until. I can the following 
    `WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(ec.element_to_be_clickable(By.XPATH,'//a[@class="ng-scope"]'))`
to confirm the first button to be clickable, but how can I confirm the second one without using the text feature(abc|efg)?

Any suggestion to extract the index within xpath? Thank you.

```
<li class="ng-scope" ng-report="one in typelist">
    <a class = "btn ng-binding" ng-class="{aabbcc}"> abc</a>
</li>
<li class="ng-scope" ng-report="one in typelist">
    <a class = "btn ng-binding" ng-class="{aabbcc}"> efg</a>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can search with xpath by index

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ec.element_to_be_clickable(By.XPATH, "//a[@class='ng-scope'][2]"))
```

This will give you the second button.

Comment: For the second ng-scope, It should be [2] not [1]. check this : [http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/locating-elements.html](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/locating-elements.html)

Comment: @dvenkatsagar I found why (although your example was some what vague, look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3319341/why-do-indexes-in-xpath-start-with-1-and-not-0)). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try Capturing all the element to a list and iterate through each for checking if they are clickable