# Xpath: matching one element based on attribute of neighboring element

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, selenium-chromedriver

I've got markup of the following format I'm attempting to work with using Selenium/Python:

```
    <tr>
        <td><a href="www.google.com">google</a></td>
        <td>useless text</td>
        <td>useless text2</td>
        <td>useless text3</td>
        <td><a href="needle@email.com">emailaddress</a></td>
    </tr>
```

The idea being that given a known email address (part of the `href` in the emailaddress `td`), I can get to (and click) the `a` in the first `td`. It looks like xpath is the best choice to accomplish this with Selenium. I'm trying the following xpath:

```
//*[@id="page_content"]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/div/table[1]/tbody/tr/td[4]/a[contains(@href, "mailto:needle@email.com")]/../../td/a[0]
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"xpathhere"}
```

I do know the xpath to get to the "needle@email.com" a is correct, as it's just copied from chrome dev tools, so the error must be with the part of the xpath after reaching the first `a` element. Can anyone shed some light on the problem with my xpath?

Comment: maybe just `//a[contains(@href, "needle@email.com")]` ?

Comment: The problem is I'm attempting to retrieve the `a` in the first `td`, so I need to figure out how to get back to that level once the "needle@email.com" `a` is matched.

Comment: You should avoid using indexes, always use something you know will not change, like part of an attribute for example, using indexes is a bad practice and not very flexible.

Comment: The best answer is @Andersson's. No index, robust against unexpected issues and Selenium state of the art practices.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use below code:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait as wait

xpath = '//td[a[@href="needle@email.com"]]/preceding-sibling::td/a'
wait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, xpath))).click()
```

This should allow you to match first link based on `href` attribute of the last link in table row (`tr`) and click it once it became clickable

Comment: No index, noisily robust against unexpected issues and Selenium state of the art practices.

Answer (score 1):

First, note that (this may be a meaningless typo) you are looking for "mailto:needle@email.com" while the value of your href attribute is "needle@email.com".

Second, you actually *know how to get back [...]*. But [Xpath indexing starts with 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3319341/why-do-indexes-in-xpath-start-with-1-and-not-0). Thus why this `'a[0]'`, is this also a meaningless typo ?

Anyway, this xpath would get your sibling

```
'//a[contains(@href, "needle@email.com")]/../../td[1]/a[1]'
```

Or more accurately than using `contains` (since you may have other email adresses that can be matched, e.g. "otherneedle@email.com")

```
'//a[@href="needle@email.com"]/../../td[1]/a[1]'
```

Or even better, i.e. with no index and no parent/child like exploration.

```
'//td[a[@href="needle@email.com"]]/preceding-sibling::td/a'
```

All tested.

Answer (score 0):

Try to find the `tr` that contains that email, and click on the first link from it.

```
//tr[.//a[contains(@href, 'your_email')]]//a
```

or

```
//tr[.//a[contains(@href, 'your_email')]]//a[@href]
```

or

```
//tr[.//a[contains(@href, 'your_email')]]//a[contains(@href, 'common_url_part')]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML should be this.

```
<tr>
    <td><a href="www.google.com">google</a></td>
    <td>useless text</td>
    <td>useless text2</td>
    <td>useless text3</td>
    <td><a href="mailto:needle@email.com">emailaddress</a></td>
</tr>
```

Otherwise, your user can click on the link until he or she works himself into a frenzy. :)

Then you can do this in selenium.

```
>>> from selenium import webdriver
>>> driver = webdriver.Chrome()
>>> driver.get("file://c:/scratch/temp2.htm")
>>> link = driver.find_element_by_xpath('.//a[contains(@href,"needle@email.com")]')
>>> link.click()
```

I've used `contains` because an email address in a link can be something like `mailto:Jose Greco <needle.email.com>`.

PS: And incidentally I've just executed this stuff on my machine.