# xpath with index not working as a selector

Tags: javascript, xpath, nightwatch.js

The page has 3 buttons with a certain text {text}. I want to be able to click on the first such button.

I tested an xpath on chrome console with the index and that gives out the correct button.

> $x("//button[contains(text(), 'sometext')]")[0]

But when I use the exact same xpath as a selector in my nightwatch code, it doesn't seem to find it.

Whereas

> selector: '//button[contains(text(), "sometext")]'

does seem to find 3 buttons but when I add [0] (as above) it fails to find the element.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3319341/why-do-indexes-in-xpath-start-with-1-and-not-0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try [1] instead of [0]. Xpath is 1 based.