# Accesing a second tag with beatifoulsoup

Tags: python

I started working on some website scraping projects and I stumbled accros some difficulties selecting a second tag within the same parent tag. I've tried using google but i still couldn't cleary understand it.

My code looks like this:

```
url = 'url to site'
content = requests.get(url).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(content, 'lxml')

car_add = soup.find('div', class_='offer-wrapper')

ad_title = car_add.find('h3', class_='lheight22 margintop5').a.strong.text
ad_price = car_add.find('p', class_='price').text
ad_location = car_add.find('td', class_='bottom-cell').div.p.small.span.text
ad_time_and_location = car_add.find('td', class_='bottom-cell').div.p
print(ad_time_and_location.prettify())
```

This prints out the following:

```
<p class="lheight16">
 <small class="breadcrumb x-normal">
  <span>
   <i data-icon="location-filled">
   </i>
   Otopeni
  </span>
 </small>
 <small class="breadcrumb x-normal">
  <span>
   <i data-icon="clock">
   </i>
    09:25
  </span>
 </small>
</p>
```

What I want to do is access the string '09:25' but when I type:

```
ad_location = car_add.find('td', class_='bottom-cell').div.p.small.span.text
```

Then it automatically defaults to the first text tag.

I've tried using the select() method but it gave me an empty list. Could anyone help me with this ?

Thank you!

Comment: Please supply a MCVE example. Since we don't have all your input HTML, please skip the requests code and just give us the HTML snippet needed to reproduce this.

Comment: you can use `find_all('span')` to get list with all `span` and later use `[1]` to get second element from list.

Comment: lxml .xpath syntax is better, you can have subscript [1] directly inside the expression

Comment: The `.xpath` solution is [How to select first element via XPath?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3319341/why-do-indexes-in-xpath-start-with-1-and-not-0)

Comment: @smci , thanks for the tip buddy . I'm really new to webscraping, I'm just now learning about these parsers. Thanks again!

Comment: xpath is incredibly powerful, instead of writing code that assumes the HTML has a certain structure and manually navigates it. If you post the actual url (to make this example MCVE), then I'll post the xpath code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `find_all('span')` to get list with all `span` and later use `[1]` to get second element from list.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS

text = '''<p class="lheight16">
 <small class="breadcrumb x-normal">
  <span>
   <i data-icon="location-filled">
   </i>
   Otopeni
  </span>
 </small>
 <small class="breadcrumb x-normal">
  <span>
   <i data-icon="clock">
   </i>
    09:25
  </span>
 </small>
</p>'''

soup = BS(text, 'html.parser')

item = soup.find('p').find_all('span')[1].get_text(strip=True)

print(item)
```

Comment: Thank you so much ! It worked out real nice. I wish you a nice day :)

Comment: @GhirasimDaniel you can mark answer as accepted. And when you will have enough reputation you can upvote it.

Comment: I just marked it, forgot about that yesterday. Thanks for the reminder ! :)