# In selenium, how to located two elements have same span class name?

Tags: selenium

I need use selenium to located two elements. However, they both have same span class name. My code:

```py
select_button = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//span[@class='mat-button-wrapper']")
```

The issue is: I can this command 10 times, 6 times it locates my element, ( select button), but the other 4 times, it landed on the other button. How do I make sure it is 10  out of 10 times it will located my "select " button?

Comment: Can you add a sample of your HTML to your question?

Answer (score 2):

In case there are 2 elements with the same `xpath` as you mentioned you can use `(//span[@class='mat-button-wrapper'])[1]` `xpath` to access the first element and `(//span[@class='mat-button-wrapper'])[2]` for the second.
However I guess it's possible to locate the desired element with relation to some other element. I will do it if you present the web page link.

Comment: Shouldn't the first element have the index "0"? i.e. (//span[@class='mat-button-wrapper'])[0]

Comment: Xpath indexation starts with 1. https://stackoverflow.com/q/3319341/3485434