# Programming languages where indexing starts at 1?

Tags: programming-languages, design-decisions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [List of 1-indexed programming languages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1499749/list-of-1-indexed-programming-languages)

Besides AWK, are there other programming languages where indexing starts at 1 instead of 0?