# How to fetch 4 characters from a string in oracle?

Tags: sql, database, oracle

By using following query i am able to fetch a particular string.Now this output string contains alphanumeric characters.e.g.abcd123,pqrs542356.
Now i want to fetch only first 4 characters of this string which will be always alpha bates.

Query::

```
(SELECT SUBSTR(in_msg, INSTR( in_msg,'?', 1, 10 )+ 1, INSTR(in_msg,'?', 1, 11 ) - INSTR( in_msg,'?', 1, 10 )- 1)
 FROM emp_message 
WHERE emp_no IN (SELECT emp_no 
                   FROM main_table 
                  WHERE name like '%abcd%')
```

This query returns output as e.g.abcd1234,pqrs145423.
Again i want to fetch only first 4 characters from this query output.
Can somebody help me in this.

Answer (score 4):

You can use substr (like you already do):

```
SUBSTR(value, 1, 4)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here it is:

```
SUBSTR(field, 0, 4)
```

Comment: @Thilo: oops, it is not obvious though :-S

Comment: 0 is treated as 1, and negative indexes count from the right side: http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/ora/sql/substr.html

Comment: @Thilo: i know about negatives. I meant that all programming languages count char position from 0.

Comment: Not all ;-)  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1499749/list-of-1-indexed-programming-languages

Answer (score 0):

```
select substr(x, 1, 4) from
   ( select x from .....  )
```