# Are there any programming languages that starts counting from 1?

Tags: coding-style, programming-languages

High level programming languages are made to be understandable to humans, but 0 is usually not accepted as a natural number in mathematics. I do not understand why all programming languages I have seen always start counting from 0, eg. int[0] = 1st element instead of int[1] = 1st element. I want to know whether there are any programming languages that support this? If not, why?

Comment: Duplicate of (closed) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1499749/list-of-1-indexed-programming-languages, should be closed for the same reason.

Comment: Also see http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/110804/7043 for the why. There are plenty of good reasons. Besides, whether 0 is a natural number is *not* agreed upon. There's a reason for the `N \ {0}` (natural numbers except zero) notation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, lots. Fortran for example.

And then there are languages which allow array elements to start indexing at almost any integer.  Fortran for example.

Answer (score 1):

Not so many (considering the total number of programming languages)

```
ALGOL 68
APL
AWK
CFML
COBOL
Fortran
FoxPro
Informix
Julia
Lua
Mathematica
MATLAB
PL/I
Ring
RPG
Sass
Smalltalk
Wolfram Language
XPath/XQuery
```

You can do it in Perl

```
$[ = 1;  # set the base array index to 1
```

Erlang's [tuples](http://erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/data_types.html#id65079)  and [lists](http://erlang.org/doc/man/lists.html#nth-2) index starting at 1.

Sources

- [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_programming_languages_%28array%29#Array_system_cross-reference_list)