# Need help saving a parameter to a variable each iteration

Tags: matlab, variables, for-loop, save, iteration

In the code shown, I want to save one parameter (`fval`) per iteration in one variable, but not sure how to do it. Can someone advise?

```
clear;
close all;
clc;

for i = 0 : 100
    ii = i * 0.01;
    options = optimset('Display','iter-detailed', ...
                       'Algorithm','interior point', ...
                       'Diagnostics','on');

    options.TolCon = 0;
    options.TolFun = 0;
    [X,faval,exitfag,output,lambda,grad,hessian]=fmincon(@myfun9,0,[],[],[],[],ii,1,@mycon,options);

end;
```

Comment: do you want to save the return value `fval` in a separate variable each iteration? So you will have 100 variables after the loop?

Comment: How about using an array, e.g. define `fval = [];` before the loop and then at the end of each iteration do `fval = [fval; faval];` to store the new values. Note, this will only work when `faval` has same dimensions for all iterations.

Comment: @hmofrad That's not recommended. Read why: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/preallocating-arrays.html

Comment: @Sardar_Usama I see your point!

Comment: Note that you can take all the `options...` setting out of the loop

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create 101 [separate variables](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32467170/5698672) for storing each value, that's not recommended. [Pre-allocate](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/preallocating-arrays.html) an array for `fval` for storing the values of `faval` in each iteration as shown below:

```
fval = zeros(101,1);      %Pre-allocating memory for fval
for k = 0 : 100
    ii = k * 0.01;
    options = optimset('Display','iter-detailed', ...
                       'Algorithm','interior point', ...
                       'Diagnostics','on');

    options.TolCon = 0;
    options.TolFun = 0;
    [X,faval,exitfag,output,lambda,grad,hessian]=fmincon(@myfun9,0,[],[],[],[],ii,1, ...
                       @mycon,options);

    %Storing value of faval in fval(k+1). Note that indexing starts from 1 in MATLAB
    fval(k+1) = faval;    
end
```

By the way, it seems from your code that you're not interested in the values of all other parameters i.e. `X`,`exitfag`,`output`,`lambda`,`grad`,`hessi`, because these parameters will be overwritten in each iteration. If you're not interested in these values. You can skip storing them using [tilde (`~`)](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/symbol-reference.html#bsv2dx9-1). So you might also want to use the following instead:

```
[~,faval]=fmincon(@myfun9,0,[],[],[],[],ii,1, @mycon,options);
% exitfag, output, lambda, grad, hessi are skipped automatically as per fmincon doc
```

---

<sup>**Suggested reading:**

1. [Dynamic Variables](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32467170/5698672)

2. [Preallocation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/preallocating-arrays.html)

3. [Why does MATLAB have 1 based indexing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22546787/why-does-matlab-have-1-based-indexing?)

4. [Tilde as an Argument Placeholder](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/symbol-reference.html#bsv2dx9-1)</sup>