# Basic concepts of Array

Tags: arrays, indexing

```
#include<iostream.h>

main()
{
int a[10];
return 0;
}
```

why does array index always start with zero and not with one . Need valid reason !

Comment: Because -7 looked silly. Other than that search a little, it's easy to google and there are many identical questions on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Why did you write here the code? You need some help with that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does the indexing start with zero in 'C'?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7320686/why-does-the-indexing-start-with-zero-in-c)

Comment: In some languages, array indices start with 1. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1499749/3345375).

Comment: And remember that [different tasks call for different conventions](https://xkcd.com/163/).

Answer (score 1):

Actually, there is a valid reason. It's because, an array is actually a pointer. So, A[0] means +0 from the beginning (the first position). That's why we use the 0 index.