# IndexError: string index out of range in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

My code is giving me an error saying the index is out of range on line 9. Here is my code:

```
s = 'aba'
letter = ''
substring = ''

i = 0

while(i <= len(s)):
    prev_letter = s[0]
    letter = s[i]

    if letter <= prev_letter:
        substring += letter
        prev_letter = letter

    i += 1
```

Comment: remove `=` from `while(i <= len(s)):`

Comment: To see why this happens: The string `s = 'a'` has `len(s) == 1` but does not have an index at 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As other people have indicated, `s[s.Length]` isn't actually a valid index; indices are in the [closed interval](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_(mathematics)) `[0, length - 1]` (i.e. the last valid index is `length - 1` and the first index is 0). Note that this isn't true for *every* language (there are languages where the first index is 1), but it's certainly true for Python.

Think about what an array is and how it's implemented: it's just a series of consecutive memory locations. The index is an offset from the initial memory address, **not** the item number. That's why the first item has an index of 0 - there's no offset from the address of the first item (by definition). However, the 5th item's address, for example, is `(address of the first item) + (4 * offset size)`. That's why you can access an arbitrary item in an array in constant time. (This is a "holdover" from C/C++ of sorts).

Answer (score 5):

Change `while(i <= len(s):` to `while(i < len(s)):`, or to `while(i <= len(s)-1):`

In Python, a string is a single-dimensional array of characters. Indexes in Python programming start at 0.  This means that the **maximum** index for *any* string will *always* be len(s)-1.  In your code, `i` will eventually be equal to `len(s)`, which is one element higher than the maximum.

As a side note, it would probably be beneficial to use a `for` loop rather than a `while` loop in your code.  Your code can be replaced with this:

```
s = 'aba'
letter = ''
substring = ''

i = 0

for i in range(len(s)):
    prev_letter = s[0]
    letter = s[i]

    if letter <= prev_letter:
        substring += letter
        prev_letter = letter
```

Comment: Not every programming languages are `zero-based`! in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1499795/4834682)  you can find a list of `one-based` indexing  languages.

Comment: Oh yeah, I meant to specify Python.  There are some that start at 1, like TI-BASIC.  I'll edit that now.